# SQL: Unable to set dynamic variable to OFFSET

Tags: php, sql, laravel, web

I'm trying to assign a variable to OFFSET property I tried concat too but I'm not doing it right. First is my original code and the second one is where I've tried to concat the variable to the offset.

```
SELECT * FROM( SELECT id, title, content, userc_id, created_at, is_deleted FROM stories
UNION
SELECT id, heading AS title, description AS content, userc_id, created_at, is_deleted FROM causes
) AS a
JOIN (SELECT clients.* FROM clients) AS b ON a.userc_id = b.id
LEFT JOIN (SELECT files.* FROM files ) AS c ON c.table_id = a.id AND (c.table = "stories" OR c.table = "causes") 
WHERE a.is_deleted = 0
ORDER BY a.created_at
LIMIT 1
OFFSET $offset');
```

**Please help to me to optimize this code a better way too.
Here is where I've tried doing concat but I failed miserably.**

```
SELECT * FROM( SELECT id, title, content, userc_id, created_at, is_deleted FROM stories
UNION
SELECT id, heading AS title, description AS content, userc_id, created_at, is_deleted FROM causes
) AS a
JOIN (SELECT clients.* FROM clients) AS b ON a.userc_id = b.id
LEFT JOIN (SELECT files.* FROM files ) AS c ON c.table_id = a.id AND (c.table = "stories" OR c.table = "causes") 
WHERE a.is_deleted = 0
ORDER BY a.created_at
CONCAT(LIMIT 1 OFFSET $offset) ');
```

Comment: I'm just assuming that it's in single quotes from the end which is `');`, happy to delete if wrong.

Comment: What seems to be the problem? Do you get any errors? And what database are you using?